# Keep getting EOF while sending nested http requests

Tags: go

I have a client and two servers (both the servers in Go). All the solutions pertain to sending multiple requests from one server to another. But I am trying to implement this type of communication:

```
Client         Server A        Server B
Request1  -->  Received
               Request 2  -->  Received
               Received   <--  Request 3
               Response 3 -->  Received
               Received   <--  Response 2
Received  <--  Response 1
```

However, I am consistently getting the EOF error in the response to Request 2. I have read several articles on the topic, and tried all possible solutions but nothing has resolved this issue. Here is the code that I have written for sending the POST request. The same code is being called by both Server A and Server B.

```
func SendPost(url string, insecureSkipVerify bool, authHeader *CAuthHeader, contentType string, otherHeaders map[string]string, body string, v interface{}) (string, error) {
    bBody := strings.NewReader(body)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bBody)
    if err != nil {
        return "", utilities.GetError("01: ", err.Error())
    }
    req.Close = true

    if authHeader != nil {
        req.Header.Set(authHeader.GetHeaderStrings())
    }
    req.Header.Set(HEADERKEY_CONTENTTYPE, contentType)

    for k, v := range otherHeaders {
        req.Header.Set(k, v)
    }

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: insecureSkipVerify},
    }

    utilities.DebugLog("-------> SENDING POST: %s", url)
    netClient := &http.Client{Timeout: 40 * time.Second, Transport: tr}

    resp, err := netClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // GETTING ERROR LOG HERE IN REQUEST 2
        utilities.DebugLog("<------- RECEIVED POST: %s, with error: %s", url, err.Error())
        return "", utilities.GetError("02: ", err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    utilities.DebugLog("<------- RECEIVED POST: %s", url)
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", utilities.GetError("03: ", err.Error())
    }

    utilities.DebugLog("%s", string(b))

    // MAY IGNORE THIS, JUST POPULATES THE RESPONSE INTO THE interface() PASSED AS A PARAMETER TO THIS FUNCTION
    if err := populateInterface(b, v); err != nil {
        return string(b), err
    }

    utilities.DebugLog("Received body: %s", string(b))

    return string(b), nil
}
```

The logs that I get on server A are:

```
2019-02-21 18:33:57.579758 +0530 IST m=+80.025904414: -------> SENDING POST: http://localhost:7350/v2/rpc/refreshPublicProfile?http_key=defaultkey
2019-02-21 18:34:13.517802 +0530 IST m=+95.963470623: <------- RECEIVED POST: http://localhost:7350/v2/rpc/refreshPublicProfile?http_key=defaultkey, with error: Post http://localhost:7350/v2/rpc/refreshPublicProfile?http_key=defaultkey: EOF
```

And the logs on Server B are:

```
2019-02-21 18:33:57.586869 +0530 IST m=+74.893470343: -------> SENDING POST: http://localhost:8103/publicprofile
2019-02-21 18:34:13.513541 +0530 IST m=+90.819664927: <------- RECEIVED POST: http://localhost:8103/publicprofile
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You’re discarding the Transport (which is missing a number of useful defaults) after each request. It may not be related to your error, but leaking connections is not doing you any good.

Comment: @JimB thanks for pointing this out. Let me look into it and fix it. Can you point me to the default values that I must use? As for the problem, it seems to be occurring due to the long time taken by request 3. I reduced the time in request 3 and the issue ceased to exist. Since the request 2 remained idle for a long time, the connection closed in the background.

Comment: The useful defaults are in the `DefaultTransport`. Without a [mcve] there may not be much we can do (and unsurprisingly, creating a standalone example will often show you the problem)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with golang http package, but with Server B, which is a third party server that doesn't send a response if the request runs for more than 10s. Thus the server A received the error as listed above. However, noteworthy learnings, both attributed to @JimB :

1. Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example proved to be extremely helpful since I ended up creating one and didn't observe the same error there. This led me to believe that the issue has to do with Server B, which is a third party application. I have submitted a bug with their team, who are looking into it now.
2. Have now constructed the transport using default values:

```
    tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    if tr.TLSClientConfig == nil {
        tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: insecureSkipVerify}
    } else {
        tr.TLSClientConfig.InsecureSkipVerify = insecureSkipVerify      
    }
```

Turns out that this was a false alarm that I wasted a couple of days in. Unsure if this will help anyone, but still thought of posting the details of how this was resolved eventually.

Comment: why do yo say it timeouts after 10s and not 40s ?

Comment: 10s was the timeout set by the third party service which I was hitting. The timeout being hit was at their end, not mine.